# How to merge conflicts in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My team is using Visual Studio Code and TFSVC.  When we have a conflict, Visual Studio seems to give two options:  `Keep Yours` or `Take Theirs`.  There doesn't seem to be an option to actually merge the code together, manually. I need to keep my method while also bringing in my teammates method.  How do you do this in Visual Studio Code?

[image]

Comment: As a work around; you can open visual studio professional, go to to the team explorer tab and then perform the merge there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported by the version control extension that you are using. According to the [official docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#resolving-conflicts), the only "resolve" commands they support are the two that you have already found:

> - Resolve: Take Theirs – Resolves the conflict as Take Theirs.
> - Resolve: Keep Yours – Resolves the conflict as Keep Yours.

You can open a feature request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/new).